# Cython logging filename & module

Tags: logging, cython

If you [call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.info) the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) from [cythonised](http://cython.org/) code including [funcName and module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) then you get wrong values for those attributes.  Instead you get the values from the first higher level caller that wasn't from cython, which is extremely misleading.  The reason is that cython doesn't [generate call frames](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/limitations.html#stack-frames), so they are invisible to the logging.findCaller method.

Is there a way to make logging work with cython?

I do not wish to change every location that calls logging.  I'm happy to monkeypatch logging.findCaller if there is an alternate way of finding the information.

Comment: Does `logging` collect that kind of information for any compiled code, not just cythonized, but C-api functions from `numpy` or Python itself?

Comment: logging.findCaller is what gathers the information.  I doubt anyone calls logging directly from C code because it is quite tedious to setup.  No idea about numpy since I don't use it.  In my case a simple hello.py calling logging works fine, cythonise it and the log message shows incorrect function and module information.

Comment: Cythonizing turns the functions into `c` code, so it is no longer running in the python stack.

Comment: I don't care how logging can be made to work, just any way that will.  Cython could construct the stack frame objects, but doesn't do so by default except during exceptions.

Comment: I don't believe this is readily possible: Python doesn't let you modify the call stack yourself. It's easily possible to add info to a traceback (which is what Cython does) but that only makes sense after an except has been raised. You could try using [`logging`'s fallback trick of adding a raise/catch](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/75f0b5dbac3376a3b36c943ec867c0daed35eb4f/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L159) but I'm pretty sure you'd have to do that every time in Cython rather than monkeypatching `findCaller`

Comment: The fallback won't work since control has to return back up the call chain for cython to add stack frames after the fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short term answer is that cython doesn't add stack frames and doesn't have configuration to do so (except for exceptions, after the fact as the stack is unwound).  Developers on the mailing list are considering adding them as an option, with logging being another example of why they are needed.

A short term workaround is to adjust the code (programmatically) during compilation to stash frame information (method name, module, line number etc) into thread local variables, and monkey patch logging.findCaller to get those details that way if available.